# Disable direct access to file, but still allow it to be embeded

Tags: php, security, video, hotlinking

I'm currently making a website with videos on it, however, I want to avoid as much as possible people being able to download them (I know that this is not 100% achievable, but there are ways to make it harder).

Here's my filesystem

```
- main folder/
  - watch.php
  - videos/
    - .htaccess
    - example video.mp4
    - streamer.php
```

And here's my code
**Watch.php:**

```
<video src="videos/streamer.php"></video>
```

**streamer.php:**

```
<?php
       $stream = new VideoStream("example video.mp4");
       $stream->start();
?>
```

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?([^/]+)/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %2#%{HTTP_HOST} !^(.+)#(www\.)?\1$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(php|mp4)$ - [F,L,NC]
```

**Additional:** The server is running loacally, and such does **not** have a domain name.

The video streams fine from `watch.php` **but** if you open the video source (streamer.php) you will be allowed onto the page, where you can then download the content.

What I **want** to happen is for the video to stream fine to `watch.php` but if you open `streamer.php` you are blocked from seeing the content.

Can anyone help me with this? I've tried just about every solution I've looked up and I can't manage to get any to work. Thanks

**[EDIT]**: Most preferably, this would be done in the `.htaccess` file so that I can also block people from entering `example video.mp4`

Comment: check `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and think how you can use it to do what you want

Comment: Can you force people to be logged in in order to view?

Comment: Theoretically I can, but I wouldn't like for it to be a requirement

Comment: Like everything sent to the browser, you can usually just open the browser inspection tools, go to the network/resources area, right-click and save as most things because this code isn't really streaming, it is downloading. There's some optimizations for range-seeking, but it is still just downloading really. If you really want to secure this you might be better off with a real video streaming protocol such as RTSP.